# Java search for specific name in sql

Tags: java, sql

```
    public void pretraga_vina(){
    out.println("Enter name of wine you want to search:");
    Scanner upis=new Scanner(ulaz);
    String odabir=upis.nextLine();


    Statement statement;
    try{
        statement = connect.createStatement();
        String upit="SELECT * FROM wine WHERE wine_name LIKE ?";
        PreparedStatement prepared = connect.prepareStatement(upit);

        prepared.setString(1, odabir);
        out.println(prepared.toString());
        ResultSet resultSet = prepared.executeQuery();

        while(resultSet.next()){
            out.println(resultSet.getString("wine_name")+", "+resultSet.getInt("year"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Problem is when i enter wine name i got no resault. can you help me?

Comment: Is there something in your table?

Comment: What does `out.println(prepared.toString());` print? Also, are you sure the `wine` table contains rows that match your query?

Comment: there seems to be a problem with nextline printing. Im working with server client operations using telnet. The query is correct and its working fine but the problem seems to be with the nextLine function, it doesnt return what it should

Answer (score 0):

Is there a wine name in your table that matches what you are searching for? Also make sure if you want **partial** matches (as opposed to exact ones) you append and prepend the "%" character, so `"wine_name"` becomes `"%wine_name%"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL LIKE query, make sure to add `%` characters before, after or both sides of your user input.

```
prepared.setString(1, "'%" + odabir + "%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL like function should prefixed or postfixed with "%", for example:

```
SELECT * FROM suppliersWHERE supplier_name like '%bob%';
```

so please correct the query.

Answer (score 0):

prepared.setString(1, "%" + searchTerm "%");

Comment: Add more details to your answer, so it becomes clearer.